# Track code changes to specific functions

Tags: version-control, notifications

Not sure how to even search for this topic so I'm just going to ask. I have a couple places in my code where changes to one function have to be also made to a similar function. Basically the operations in the functions are very similar but the data being worked on is different.

I don't like it but for now that's how it is. My question is anyone knows of a way or a tool that will notify me if a certain function has changed. If I get the notification I know to confirm the changes were made to other function.

Please don't tell me to change my code. I know this isn't ideal and thought has been put into alternatives, but nothing elegant has popped up.

Thanks,
Gunner

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea I have. Maybe it will set the train of thought...

I can add a special comment in my code for a block that I want to be tracked. The comment will have opening and closing syntax:

my_code.php...

```
//track-start-1234
[CODE]
//track-end-1234

//track-start-5678
[CODE]
//track-end-5678
```

I will then have a script that I tell to check a list of files, my_code.php, for now. It will look for the special comment syntax. "1234" will represent a file that holds the last modified code for that function, so 1234.php. If the contents between the comments do not match the code stored in the file then an alert is fired. Also I might add a relationship to the other code so the alert says something like

```
Code 1234 has changed. Please make sure code 5678 has been updated as well.
```

I think I can add this script to GIT somehow so it either is part of the core git commands like "push" or maybe just another command I have to run as part of our deployment process. A second option might be adding it to phpstorm's code inspector or something like that.

When the code has been modified and everything is good I will just manually copy the new code into the comparison file. There will not be a ton of updates so this will not be too tedious.

For now this is probably the route I'll go, but any critiques or suggestions are definately welcome.